# Laravel Error In Log Multiple Times A Day

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, error-logging

Here is the error:

```
[2015-07-01 00:12:19] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:148
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1054): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1022): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1001): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 {main} [] []
```

I have absolutely no idea where this error is coming from, and I'm tired of having my logs loaded with it.

Comment: Cannot you add some lines in your code to, also, log the page being tried to access. May be that can give you a clue about what might be happening.

Comment: Looks like it could be caused by anyone just going to a 404 page on your website. Do you have a `DocumentError 404 page.html` set in your httpd.conf/other?

Comment: Test all the routes on your application manually by navigating to them (preferably do this in a non-production environment). When you come to one that returns a 404 error, you know where this message is coming from.

Comment: Is there not a way to have the log TELL me what the Route is? Seems like an obvious thing...

Comment: Yes and no. You can specify when to write to the log using (I think) `Log::error()` and could manually write the current url, but the entry you see above is what shows up when you navigate to a url that returns a 404 error. If `"debug" => true` you would see it on screen and it gets logged to your error log. If `"debug" => false`, you wouldn't see this error on screen, it would *only* get logged.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an exception handler, check to see if the exception is an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException` and if so, log the request path so you know which route it was that was hit.

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code) {
    if ($exception instanceof Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
        Log::error('Invalid Route', ['route' => Request::path()]);
    }
});
```

I put this in `app/start/global.php`.

Then next time it happens, check `laravel.log` for the words `Invalid Route` and it should give you some idea what's happening.  Keep in mind it may not even be your users which are doing this.  I've done something similar in production and usually get a few of these errors a day with bots just hitting random things looking for something to access.